# bond0: An illegal loopback occurred on adapter (em2)

Tags: networking, network-bonding

**log
Oct 30 14:25:49 blade17-1-1 kernel: [  758.641314] bond0: An illegal loopback occurred on adapter (em2)
Oct 30 14:25:49 blade17-1-1 kernel: [  758.641314] Check the configuration to verify that all adapters are connected to 802.3ad compliant switch ports
**end log

nic is 10.40 intel using i40e driver
bond is lacp across dell mxl in vtl.
ubutu 14.04

The bond functions correctly just continually fils the logs with the above error.  This does not occur using other bonding modes.  It also does not occur on redhat.

Any assistance in quieting these errors would be appreciated.

Comment: Get a new adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Though the specifics are different, I was experiencing this same result recently with an Intel X710 10GbEx2 card in CentOS using i40e 1.3.38, connected via 802.3ad to a Brocade MLXe. LACP was working fine, but the errors would persist every 30 seconds. Updating the driver to a recent version (1.3.47) has resolved the errors for me.

You can check your driver version with `modinfo i40e`.